# Numerical stability of a matrix inversion problem

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-decomposition

Suppose, we have a matrix X with dimension m and n.
Now lets say, we are interested to find the inverse of the covariance matrix: $X^T X$. The straightforward way to do it is to compute the matrix $X^T  X$ and perform the inversion operation $(X^T  X)^{-1}$. But we also know from SVD decomposition

$$X= USV^T \\ X^TX = VS^TUU^TSV^T=VS^TSV^T=VS^2V^T 
\\ \text{since } (X^T X)^{-1}(X^T X) = I
\\ \text{and }(V(S^2)^{-1}V^T)(VS^2V^T )= V(S^2)^{-1}S^2V^T = VV^T = I$$

we can alternatively calculate $V(S^2)^{-1}V^T$ to find the inverse of $X^T X$. But I have found experimentally that for m>>n, both yield the same answer but for m << n (e.g., m=100, n=1000), this is not the case. I have attached a python code snippet for this also.

Can someone explain why and if there is any remedy for it? Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np


def inverse_delta(x):
  u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(x,  full_matrices=False)
  v = vh.T
  inverse = np.linalg.inv(x.T@x)
  inverse_tilde = (v@np.diag(1/(s**2)))@v.T
  print(np.linalg.norm(inverse-inverse_tilde))


inverse_delta(x = np.random.randn(1000, 100))
3.448652345497296e-17
inverse_delta(x = np.random.randn(100, 1000))
8797061188866344.0
```

Comment: If $m<n$, then $X$ becomes so-called "wide" matrix, so $X^TX$ is not invertible (it has at least $n-m$ zero eigenvalues). But in this case $XX^T$ is (or might be) invertible.

Comment: ah, I see, when a matrix is not invertible, then does it matter how I calculate it? namely $X^TX$ or the way I showed

Comment: When a matrix is not invertible you are basically trying to calculate something like $1/0$ and depending on the machine precision (the precision of floating point number in your computations) and the order of operations you can get vastly different numbers like in your example.

Comment: Assume that $X$ has max range, then $XX^t$ will be invertible but it will have very bad condition number. Check the condition numbers of  $XX^t$.